# Error: undefined columns selected in MC simulation

Tags: r, dataframe, r-lavaan

I'd like to run a MC simulation with the simsem and lavaan package and run into an error with a data.frame. I specified the df as

```
N.per.group <- 50
exoData <- data.frame(X = rep(1:0, each = N.per.group))
```

and define the model as follows

```
simMod1 <-
  model.path(
    BE = endoPaths, # matrix containing variables to be estimated
    RPS = residCor, # covariance matrix of residuals among variables
    KA = exoPaths, # matrix containing variables to be estimated
    con = userParams,
    indLab = rownames(kappa.free),
    covLab = colnames(kappa.free)
  )
rejectMCCI <- function(object) {
  CIs <- semTools::monteCarloCI(object)
  apply(CIs, 1, function(CI)
    0 < CI["ci.lower"] | 0 > CI["ci.upper"])
}
out1 <-
  sim(
    nRep = 5000,
    model = simMod1,
    covData = exoData,
    n = nrow(exoData),
    seed = 777,
    outfun = rejectMCCI
  )
```

However, I run into this error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(covData, , covLab, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

What is the solution to this problem here? Thank you very much!

The line

```
covData = exoData
```

seems to be the issue here by referencing the df from the beginning.

The procedure is based on [Donelly et al. (2022)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-022-01996-0).

Comment: We can't help you without a reproducible example